# Selenium with Python - html report is not showing any logs in any of my tests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, reporting

I´m new to Stackoverflow, automated testing and programming in general so please be patient with this junior.

I have been able to automate 359 tests for my company and all 359 pass correctly. I was doing a Selenium course and discovered the logging possibility and the one of creating a html report when running the tests as "pytest -s -v --html=report.html etc"

My issue is that the report.html gets created and shows no content for the tests, only the name of each test.

Please let me know how can I fix this. I will now paste the beggining of my script. Since the first 25 lines of code are repeated in every test i put it in a fixture inside a class and, even tough the code might be quite messy, it works well, but i would like to be able to put logs into the code and have them into my html reports so that non technical people can understand what is being done by the tests and where it is failing if they do.

```
import pytest
import unittest
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
import random
import log_config
logger = log_config.set_up_logging()
chromedriver_path = os.environ.get("CHROME_PATH")
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + chromedriver_path
from settings import CON_SELFSERVICE_URL
from locators import *
from baseclass import BaseClass


class Test_CON_02_Coupons(unittest.TestCase, BaseClass):
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, request):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(60)
        self.vars = {}
        self.driver.get(CON_SELFSERVICE_URL)
        yield
        self.driver.quit()
    
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def login_and_navigate(self, setup):
        self.driver.find_element(*username_field).click()
        self.driver.find_element(*username_field).send_keys(valid_username)
        self.driver.find_element(*password_field).click()
        self.driver.find_element(*password_field).send_keys(valid_password)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(login_button))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.driver.find_element(*login_button).click()
        time.sleep(1) 
        alert_visible = self.driver.execute_script("""
            var element = document.querySelector(arguments[0]);
            return element !== null && element.offsetParent !== null;
        """, Login_Alert[1])
        if alert_visible:
            self.driver.find_element(*username_field).click()
            self.driver.find_element(*username_field).clear()
            self.driver.find_element(*username_field).send_keys(valid_username)
            self.driver.find_element(*password_field).click()
            self.driver.find_element(*password_field).clear()
            self.driver.find_element(*password_field).send_keys(valid_password)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(login_button))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.driver.find_element(*login_button).click()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((menu_couponsv3)))
        self.driver.find_element(*menu_couponsv3).click()
        iframe = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((coupons_iframe)))
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    def test_coupons_03_Search_by_Title(self):
        # Being able to conduct a coupon search based on a Title
        log = self.getLogger() 
        self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".app-headline__subtitle")))
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,\'mat-input-0\')]").click()
        log.info("Click on search bar")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").send_keys("100")
        log.info("Input of -100-")
        assert "100" in self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.mat-cell.cdk-cell.--long-text.--is-clickable.cdk-column-i18nFields.mat-column-i18nFields.ng-star-inserted > span').text
        log.info("Checking that the inputed value is in the title of the first option of the grid")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").click()
        log.info("Click on search bar")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").clear()
```

I was importing the logging function from another file named baseclass.py with which I am getting correctly a file named logfile.log with all the logs the same way I would like it to be in the html report.

This is the content of that file:

```
import inspect
import logging

class BaseClass:
    def getLogger(self):
        loggerName= inspect.stack()[1][3]
        logger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("logfile.log")
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s :%(levelname)s : %(name)s :%(message)s")
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        return logger
```

Please help me achieve the goal of having good html reports with the correct logs displayed inside.

Thank you very much!

I did so many changes back and forth with the code that I ended up coming back to the point where everything worked and just came here for help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `pytest-html` reports, the test data section gets filled with stack traces and exceptions (for failing tests), and skip reasons for tests marked as skipped. Here's an example html report generated after running `pytest` with `--html=report.html` for a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) test suite of example tests:

```bash
pytest --html=report.html
```

[image]

Like in your examples, SeleniumBase tests inherit `unittest.TestCase` and run with `pytest`.

There are ways of changing defaults for the html-report generated by your local framework. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3455#issuecomment-441564933 for a good example, which has the important `pytest` parts that you'll need to use, such as `@pytest.mark.hookwrapper`, `pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)`, `pytest_html.extras.html`, `extra.append`, and `report.extra`. But if you like the report that you saw in the screenshot, see [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) for the code, or just use that framework for your tests.